# How to fix this invalid php code

Tags: php, wordpress

In my error.log I'm seeing this appear multiple times before I suffer serious memory leaks

> PHP Warning: implode() [function.implode]: Invalid arguments passed in /home/daxcentr/public_html/wp-content/themes/reload/masonry-layout/fishtail/style.php on line 3

The code style.php is here:

```html
<?php $mediaUrl = wmlp_layout_url(__FILE__); // Donot remove this ?>
<style>
.wmle_container .wmle_item{box-shadow:<?php echo implode($layoutSettings['box_shadow'],' '); ?>; margin:10px;-webkit-border-radius: <?php echo implode($layoutSettings['box_border'],' '); ?>; border-radius: <?php echo implode($layoutSettings['border_radius'],' '); ?>;}
.wmle_container .wmle_item .wpme_image a{ display:block; padding:10px;}
.wmle_container .wmle_item .wpme_image img{box-shadow:none !important; display:block; margin:auto;-webkit-border-radius: <?php echo $layoutSettings['border_radius'][0]; ?> <?php echo $layoutSettings['border_radius'][1]; ?> 0 0;
border-radius: <?php echo $layoutSettings['border_radius'][0]; ?> <?php echo $layoutSettings['border_radius'][1]; ?> 0 0;}
.wmle_container .wmle_item .wmle_post_title{ font-size:<?php echo $layoutSettings['title_font_size']; ?>;color:<?php echo $layoutSettings['title_font_color']; ?>; line-height:1.3; padding:10px 10px 10px 10px; font-weight:bold; background:<?php echo $layoutSettings['title_bg_color']; ?>;}
.wmle_container .wmle_item:hover .wmle_post_title{ background:<?php echo $layoutSettings['title_bg_hover_color']; ?>; color:<?php echo $layoutSettings['title_font_hover_color']; ?>;}
.wmle_container .wmle_item .wmle_post_title a{ color:inherit; text-decoration:none;}
.wmle_container .wmle_item .wmle_post_meta{background:<?php echo $layoutSettings['social_bg_color']; ?>; padding:7px 10px 7px 10px; font-size:12px; border-top:<?php echo implode($layoutSettings['social_bar_separator'],' '); ?>;color:<?php echo $layoutSettings['social_font_color']; ?>;}
.wmle_container .wmle_item .wmle_post_meta a{ text-decoration:none; color:inherit;}
.wmle_container .wmle_item .wmle_social_share{display:block; float:left; height:20px;}
.wmle_container .wmle_item .wmle_comment_count{display:block; float:right;}
.wmle_container .wmle_item .wmle_social_share a{display:inline-block; width:20px; height:20px; overflow:hidden; text-indent:-200px; background-repeat:no-repeat; background-position:center;}
.wmle_container .wmle_item .wmle_social_share a.fb{background-image:url(<?php echo $mediaUrl ?>/facebook.png);}
.wmle_container .wmle_item .wmle_social_share a.tw{background-image:url(<?php echo $mediaUrl ?>/twitter.png);}
.wmle_container .wmle_item .wmle_social_share a.in{background-image:url(<?php echo $mediaUrl ?>/linkedin.png);}
.wmle_container .wmle_item .wmle_social_share a.pi{background-image:url(<?php echo $mediaUrl ?>/pinterest.png);}
.wmle_container .wmle_item .wmle_social_share a.gp{background-image:url(<?php echo $mediaUrl ?>/gplus.png);}
.wmle_loadmore .wmle_loadmore_btn{ display:inline-block; padding:5px 15px;border:1px solid #e5e5e5; margin:5px;-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px -1px #959595;box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px -1px #959595; color:#454545; text-decoration:none;-webkit-border-radius: 4px;border-radius: 4px;}
</style>
```

Can you tell me what I need to change on line 3 to fix this issue?

I took this from the page using Firebug

```html
.wmle_container .wmle_item{box-shadow:0px 0px 3px -1px #959595; margin:10px;-webkit-border-radius: <br />
<b>Warning</b>:  implode() [<a href='function.implode'>function.implode</a>]: Invalid arguments passed in <b>/home/daxcentr/public_html/wp-content/themes/reload/masonry-layout/fishtail/style.php</b> on line <b>3</b><br />
; border-radius: 4px 4px 4px 4px;}
.wmle_container .wmle_item .wpme_image a{ display:block; padding:10px;}
.wmle_container .wmle_item .wpme_image img{box-shadow:none !important; display:block; margin:auto;-webkit-border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0;
border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0;}
```

Comment: Can you show us how the inputs for `box_shadow` , `box_border`, `border_radius`, `social_bar_separator` entered? It seems that you are imploding with `' '` empty space which should be okay since the values should be like `box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #aaa;`. If you can echo them without implode to see how they are saved that would be a good start I think.

Comment: whats the value of `$layoutSettings['box_shadow']`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2):

Check the syntax of `implode function.Array` should be passed as second parameter:

Syntax: `implode(separator,array)`

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply! Can you show me an example of how I can implement this to correct the PHP warning?

Comment: <?php echo implode(' ',$layoutSettings['box_shadow']); ?>  it will work only if the value of $layoutSettings['box_shadow'] is an array..